# Why I got Not a single-group group function in sql

Tags: sql

```
select 
      author.name,
      max(count(paper.pid))
from 
      paper,
      author
where 
      paper.aid=author.aid
group by 
         author,.name
```

Comment: First: `author,.name` --> `author.name`. But you can't nest aggregate functions like that. And please start using an explicit  `JOIN` operator instead of the implicit joins in the where clause

Comment: what platform are you using?

Comment: people closing because of the typographical error should not... there is a more significant issue here than that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you have a comma before "name" in your group by statement. Also, max(count()) doesn't really work or make sense. Try the below to get the author with the greatest number of papers:

```
select *
from(
select author.name,count(paper.pid)
from paper,author 
where paper.aid=author.aid 
group by author.name
order by count(paper.pid) desc
)
where rownum=1
```

And here is the sqlfiddle showing this in action: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7ed37/1/0). Jane has 2 papers and John has 3. John shows in the results.

Alternatively you can do rownum <= x where you want the top X values.

This is an Oracle 11g solution. If using some other brands of sql you'll probably want to use Top 1/Top x I believe.

Comment: nb --- this answer is specific to oracle.

Comment: top 1 and rownum don't work in DB2 there you use `FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY` at the end of the query

Answer (score 1):

Max of count does not make sense.  Do you mean this:

```
select top 1 name, paper_count
from
(
   select author.name,count(paper.pid) as paper_count
   from paper
   join author on paper.aid=author.aid 
   group by author.name
)
order by paper_count desc
```

*this answer assumes sql server.

or (as Giorgos Betsos points out:)

```
select top 1 author.name,count(paper.pid) as paper_count
from paper
join author on paper.aid=author.aid 
group by author.name
order by paper_count desc
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/7ed37/3

(Some SQL platforms won't let you order by the results of an agg function but SQL server does.)

Comment: I don't think you need the subquery.

Comment: `order by` in the subquery?

Comment: yes, but you **can** say `order by paper_count desc` in the subquery

Comment: @GiorgosBetsos - you are 100% correct -- good catch.  Answer edited.